# How to check one quantity is not assigned to two different quantities from other field

Tags: r, duplicates

Suppose I have data in following format (Actual data is much bigger):

```
   CODE    NAME    DATE    HOUR
    1       Ab    1/1/19     1
    1       Ab    1/1/19     2
    1       Ab    1/1/19     3
    2       Xy    1/1/19     1
    2       Xy    1/1/19     2
    2       Xy    1/1/19     3
    3       Ab    1/1/19     1
    3       Ab    1/1/19     2
    3       Ab    1/1/19     3
    4       Pq    1/1/19     1
    4       Pq    1/1/19     2
    4       Pq    1/1/19     3
```

How can I identify any value from NAME field is assigned to two or more values. Like here `Ab` is assigned to CODE `1` as well as `3`. The desired output is like:

```
    CODE    NAME    
     1       Ab
     3       Ab
```

I did try following and it's giving the desired output :

```
    library(dplyr)
    df1 <- df %>% distict(CODE, NAME, .keep_all = TRUE)
    df2 <- df1[duplicated(df1$NAME),]
```

I know there must be better way to do this. How it can be achieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to select `NAME` where there are more than 1 unique `CODE` and keep distinct rows.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
 group_by(NAME) %>%
 filter(n_distinct(CODE) > 1) %>%
 distinct(CODE, NAME)

#   CODE NAME 
#  <int> <fct>
#1     1 Ab   
#2     3 Ab
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(CODE = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 4L), NAME = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Ab", "Pq", "Xy"), class = "factor"), 
DATE = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = "1/1/19", class = "factor"), HOUR = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```